# Avro Json.ObjectWriter - "Not the Json schema" error

Tags: json, avro

I'm writing a tool to convert data from a homegrown format to Avro, JSON and Parquet, using Avro 1.8.0. Conversion to Avro and Parquet is working okay, but JSON conversion throws the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Not the Json schema:
{"type":"record","name":"Torperf","namespace":"converTor.torperf",
"fields":[{"name":"descriptor_type","type":"string"," 
[... rest of the schema omitted for brevity]
```

Irritatingly this is the schema that I passed along and which indeed I want the converter to use. I have no idea what Avro is complaining about. 
This is the relevant snippet of my code:

```
//  parse the schema file
Schema.Parser parser = new Schema.Parser();
Schema mySchema;
//  tried two ways to load the schema
//  like this
File schemaFile = new File("myJsonSchema.avsc");
mySchema = parser.parse(schemaFile) ;
//  and also like Json.class loads it's schema
mySchema = parser.parse(Json.class.getResourceAsStream("myJsonSchema.avsc"));

//  initialize the writer
Json.ObjectWriter jsonDatumWriter = new Json.ObjectWriter();
jsonDatumWriter.setSchema(mySchema);
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("output.avro"));
Encoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().jsonEncoder(mySchema, out);

//  append a record created by way of a specific mapping
jsonDatumWriter.write(specificRecord, encoder);
```

I replaced `myJsonSchema.avsc` with the one returned from the exception without success (and except whitespace and linefeeds they are the same). Initializing the jsonEncoder with `org.apache.avro.data.Json.SCHEMA` instead of mySchema didn't change anything either. Replacing the schema passed to Json.ObjectWriter with `org.apache.avro.data.Json.SCHEMA` leads to a NullPointerException at org.apache.avro.data.Json.write(Json.java:183) (which is a deprecated method).

From staring at org.apache.avro.data.Json.java it seems to me like Avro is checking my record schema against it's own schema of a Json record (line 58) for equality (line 73).

```
58  SCHEMA = Schema.parse(Json.class.getResourceAsStream("/org/apache/avro/data/Json.avsc"));

72  public void setSchema(Schema schema) {
73    if(!Json.SCHEMA.equals(schema))
74      throw new RuntimeException("Not the Json schema: " + schema);
75  }
```

The referenced Json.avsc defines the field types of a record:

```
{"type": "record", "name": "Json", "namespace":"org.apache.avro.data",
 "fields": [
     {"name": "value",
      "type": [
          "long",
          "double",
          "string",
          "boolean",
          "null",
          {"type": "array", "items": "Json"},
          {"type": "map", "values": "Json"}
      ]
     }
 ]
}
```

`equals` is implemented in org.apache.avro.Schema, line 346:

```
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(o == this) {
      return true;
    } else if(!(o instanceof Schema)) {
      return false;
    } else {
      Schema that = (Schema)o;
      return this.type != that.type?false:this.equalCachedHash(that) && this.props.equals(that.props);
    }
  }
```

I don't fully understand what's going on in the third check (especially  equalCachedHash()) but I only recognize checks for equality in a trivial way which doesn't make sense to me.

Also I can't find any examples or notes about usage of Avro's Json.ObjectWriter on the InterWebs. I wonder if I should go with the deprecated Json.Writer instead because there are at least a few code snippets online to learn and glean from.

The full source is available at https://github.com/tomlurge/converTor

Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little more debugging proofed that passing `org.apache.avro.data.Json.SCHEMA` to Json.ObjectWriter is indeed the right thing to do. The object I get back written to System.out prints the JSON object that I expect. The null pointer exception though did not go away.
Probably I would not have had to setSchema() of Json.ObjectWriter at all since omitting the command alltogether leads to the same NullPointerException.

I finally filed a bug with Avro and it turned out that in my code I was handing an object of type "specific" to ObjectWriter which it couldn't handle. It did return silently though and an error was thrown only at a later stage. That was fixed in Avro 1.8.1 - see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-1807 for details.